# Managing images e-Commerce

Tags: e-commerce

I am working on e-Shop project.
I my design for each product I need a picture with three sizes:

1. 480 * 480
2. 290 * 290
3. 200 * 200

Which one is better ?

- Asking e-Shop Admin to upload a picture for all above sizes.
- Asking him to upload a picture with size 480 * 480 then generating other sizes via asp.net

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Requiring your site admin to upload three separate images is simply pushing unnecessary work overhead onto the admin, and this generally results in them not bothering to create and upload three separate images for each product - resulting in an ecommerce site with missing images.

You're far better to use the technology to make the administrators life easier by requiring them to load a single image and automating the creation of the smaller sized images. Automating manual tasks is the whole point of the IT industry, and not doing so where possible  kind of defeats the purpose of building these systems.

There's not really any issue with CPU usage as you only need to generate the 2 smaller images once at the point of loading, or not at all by using CSS to resize (this may not be optimal use of bandwidth). I'd go with creating the 2 smaller images either when it is uploaded by the admin and storing it in a cache, or creating them on the fly upon the first time it is requested and then putting it into a cache.

Answer (score 1):

Upload all three images - will reduce the CPU overhead. You can then use the processing power to enable your site to be more responsive.

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, preparing three sizes of the image is a time consuming process because it must be repeated for every product.

generating would be better.

on the other hand just uploading a big one and then showing small images with css class' can be useful. (if the visitor will see all the images all the time)